# Installing KDE Plasma Desktop on Debian 9 (Stretch) -"Unable to locate package"

Tags: debian, kde, gui

I am new to Linux systems am an encountering a bit of trouble trying to install KDE Plasma. I am running an embedded PC supplied with Debian 9.13 (Stretch). The constraint is I must use the version of Debian.

When I try to run "apt-get" to install KDE Plasma Desktop, I ge:
`unable to locate package.`

I subsequently ran
`"apt-get update"` and then
`"apt-get -t stretch-backports install kde-plasma-desktop"`
however I then receive the message:

```
The value 'stretch-backports' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release 
is not available in the sources
```

I am a bit stuck at this point. I suppose I could manually download and install KDE Plasma and all the dependencies but that would take forever, and also I'm unsure which version of KDE Plasma would work with my older Debian release.

Here is the content of my sources.list file:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main
```

Any suggestions? I could go with a different GUI I suppose.
Thanks.